# How to remove systemd from Ubuntu 16.04 and prevent its usage

Tags: server, apt, upstart, systemd, pinning

I was able to enable upstart and disable systemd with commands that follows, but I was not able to prevent its auto re-installation
when invoking `apt-get install lxde` (I am used to a serious server configuration without complex gui or without gui at all).

Please help: how can I prevent systemd auto installation for both 64 and 32 bit version?
Thank you in advance.

```
apt-get install upstart-sysv sysvinit-utils -y
cp /usr/share/sysvinit/inittab /etc/inittab
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

and then

```
apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove systemd systemd:i386 -y
```

Comment: systemd can be administered with CLI

Comment: Just an FYI, this can be done but ***very*** painfully.  Since most of Ubuntu has been moved into the SystemD world, not as many have SysVInit or Upstart compatible scripts anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Found that *Debian - style pinning* works perfectly. After the command above, this resolve the situation:

```bash
apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove systemd systemd:i386 -y
echo -e 'Package: systemd\nPin: release *\nPin-Priority: -1' > /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
echo -e '\n\nPackage: *systemd*\nPin: release *\nPin-Priority: -1' >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
echo -e '\nPackage: systemd:amd64\nPin: release *\nPin-Priority: -1' >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
echo -e '\nPackage: systemd:i386\nPin: release *\nPin-Priority: -1' >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
```

Comment: As systemd becomes more and more entwined in Ubuntu and Debian, you might also want to look into the Devuan project: they're a fork of Debian that removes all systemd dependencies (including, I believe, from packages like lxde) https://devuan.org/

Comment: Using a distro for which is designed to exclude or not to be dependent on systemd is a good start. See http://without-systemd.org for a list.

Comment: I have uninstalled systemd but after rebooting i am not able to connect to the internet. (ubuntu16.04) how can i troubleshoot fix this?.

Answer (score 2):

See also the guide here: http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_an_Ubuntu_Xenial_installation#Related_pages

The inittab copy is not necessary and in that guide I address common problems of XFCE desktop environment (other DEs might have different issues with the removal of systemd)