# Is it still possible to remove systemd from Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, boot, upstart, systemd

I have read and followed the instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779640/how-to-remove-systemd-from-ubuntu-16-04-and-prevent-its-usage) (and [these](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_an_Ubuntu_Xenial_installation)). I'm working with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.3, with xfce4 installed. But after installing `upstart-sysv` and `sysvinit-utils` and doing `update-initramfs -u`, I can no longer boot -- the screen simply goes blank. So I have no idea what's wrong. Any ideas what to try?

Comment: Debian is off topic and Ubuntu is 16.04 . Is it possible, probably, easy to do, no and systemd is here to stay so I advise you learn to live with it. FWIW, AFIK, systemd is easier to work with although there is a bit of an adjustment, the majority of the adjustment is simplification of boot scripts.

Comment: Fixed the typo - I'm talking about Ubuntu of course. I know systemd is here to stay, but apparently it used to be possible to remove it, but I'm not succeeding. I'm interested in *how* to do it, or knowing that it can't be done anymore.

Comment: It used to be for one release: 15.04, when it was first introduced. The option is not supported after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can no longer usefully remove systemd, and for good reason. Many packages depend on it. Packages may ship configuration files that work with `systemd` and no other init system.

There is no practical, simple way to find out how much would break if you somehow managed to manually remove `systemd` and replace it with other init system. Even if you managed to do so, the system would not remain stable, as package updates and new installs would expect that `systemd` was present.

If you feel strongly that you don't want `systemd` in your system, I recommend using Linux distribution that is not based on it.

Comment: Yes, I've come to the same conclusion.